# R need to subset a sorted list, by percentage for each value

Tags: r, dataframe, subset

I have a dataframe sorted by the first variable that looks like:

Var1 ....

10
  10
.
.
.
  10
  11
  11 
.
.
.

et cetera.

I want to split into two dataframes, with the first containing the first n percent of the Var1==10 lines. then the first n percent of the Var1==11 lines, etc., and the second containing the last (100-n) percent of each; both still in the order of the original.

How do I do this in R?
Thanks...

Answer (score 0):

With the `iris` dataset, you could do something like

```
library("tidyverse")
N <- 10 #10 %
iris10 <- iris %>% group_by(Species) %>% slice(1:(N/ 100  * n()))
```

to get the first dataset. And then

```
iris90 <- iris %>% group_by(Species) %>% slice(-(1:(N/ 100  * n())))
```

to get the second.

Comment: Thanks a lot!  This works!  There's a little granularity - when I set N=70 for 523 instances, I get 380 and 143, or 73% and 27%, but I can live with that (or try N=67).

Comment: Not sure why that should be. When I test it with `data_frame(x = 1:523) %>% slice((1:(70/100 * n()))) %>% tail()` everything looks fine